# Get company name that is opened in Quickbooks using QBFC

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I can get the CompanyFilename using QBFC but could not get the appropriate class to get the opened company name in Quickbooks.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code, and clarify what you're looking to do. To my knowledge, the only company name you can get with QBFC *is the company file that's open*.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the company file name using QBFC.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Company Name or the File Path of the company file currently open in Quickbooks?

Comment: I can get the filpath but not the companyname (opened) using QBFC.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an older question. After searching for other answers related to the QBFC, I thought I would post an answer. It might help someone who is getting started.

The [IDN Unified OSR (Onscreen Reference)](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) is an excellent resource for this type of question. It is a little cumbersome to use. But, it will give you a sample bit of code for testing in either VB.NET or C#. You do have to know what request message you want to learn about. In this case, you are looking for `CompanyQuery`\ `ICompanyQuery`. The sample code that is generated shows how to build the request and parse the response. The function in the sample code named `BuildCompanyQueryRq` has some invalid code that you will need to change for your solution.

`CompanyQueryRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("ab");`

Change it to :

`CompanyQueryRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("CompanyName");`

That will request only the CompanyName property. If you wanted to add more properties this is were you would use the name of the property to add to the list. If you delete the line altogether, you will retrieve ALL of the fields. It is recommended to only request what you need.

**NOTE:** According to the documentation that I have read, it is case sensitive.

You then need to look at the `WalkCompanyQueryRs` function to see how to get the value returned. The sample will retrieve as much data from the response as possible. You will need to trim the code back to the requested fields.

FYI: The OSR has the ability to change the version of the SDK specification used as well when generating the reference.